# Create nested-list from unique values of first value

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a list of mutations of genes.
For that, I made a list which contains lists of two values: Gene and Alteration, which results in this:

```
Gene_names = ['GPL2', 'GWEL', 'VREI', 'GPL2', 'GPL2', 'VREI']
Mutation_names = ['R278W', 'L72K', 'M939I', 'I354S', 'F472M', 'H8F']

my_list = []
for i in range(len(Gene_names)):
    my_list.append([Gene_names[i], Mutation_names[i]])

print(my_list)
[[GPL2, R278W], [GWEL, L72K], [VREI, M939I], [GPL2, I354S], [GPL2, F472M], [VREI, H8F]]
```

As you can see, some Gene names are repeated with new alterations. What I would like to get from this previous list is another list of lists with Genes and their Alterations, like so:

```
new_list = [[GPL2, R278W, I354S, F472M], [GWEL, L72K], [VREI, M939I, H8F]]
```

In this manner, the inside lists are composed of 'First value = Gene_names', and 'Next values = Mutation_names'

That would be sort of ideal, for my particular purposes, but anything similar may also work.

Comment: I would build an intermediate dictionary to map the gene name to a list, and then file the list. Then creat your final list of lists from the dictionary.

Comment: there are only variablenames inside your statement - its not valid python code. [edit] and [mre] please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PeterWood suggested in comment you could create dictionary to group items and later you can convert it to list.

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to make it simpler

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [
    ['GPL2', 'R278W'], 
    ['GWEL', 'L72K'], 
    ['VREI', 'M939I'], 
    ['GPL2', 'I354S'], 
    ['GPL2', 'F472M'], 
    ['VREI', 'H8F']
]

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for gene, mutation in my_list:
    my_dict[gene].append(mutation)

print(my_dict)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'GPL2': ['R278W', 'I354S', 'F472M'], 'GWEL': ['L72K'], 'VREI': ['M939I', 'H8F']})
```

And convert to list (I use `[gene]` to create list becaues `all_mutations` is also list)

```
result = [ [gene]+all_mutations for gene, all_mutations in my_dict.items() ]

print(result)
```

Result

```
[['GPL2', 'R278W', 'I354S', 'F472M'], ['GWEL', 'L72K'], ['VREI', 'M939I', 'H8F']]
```

---

Full example

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [
    ['GPL2', 'R278W'],
    ['GWEL', 'L72K'],
    ['VREI', 'M939I'],
    ['GPL2', 'I354S'],
    ['GPL2', 'F472M'],
    ['VREI', 'H8F']
]

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for gene, mutation in my_list:
    my_dict[gene].append(mutation)

print(my_dict)

result = [ [gene]+all_mutations for gene, all_mutations in my_dict.items() ]

print(result)
```

and the same with normal `dict` instead of `defaultdict`

```
my_list = [
    ['GPL2', 'R278W'],
    ['GWEL', 'L72K'],
    ['VREI', 'M939I'],
    ['GPL2', 'I354S'],
    ['GPL2', 'F472M'],
    ['VREI', 'H8F']
]

my_dict = dict()

for gene, mutation in my_list:
    if gene not in my_dict:
        my_dict[gene] = []
        
    my_dict[gene].append(mutation)

print(my_dict)

result = [ [gene]+all_mutations for gene, all_mutations in my_dict.items() ]

print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example using `pandas` and `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [
    ['GPL2', 'R278W'],
    ['GWEL', 'L72K'],
    ['VREI', 'M939I'],
    ['GPL2', 'I354S'],
    ['GPL2', 'F472M'],
    ['VREI', 'H8F']
]

# convert list to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['gene', 'mutation'])

print(df)

# group by `gene`
groups = df.groupby('gene')
# convert every group to list `all_mutations`
df_groups = groups['mutation'].apply(list).reset_index(name='all_mutations')

print(df_groups)

# convert two columns to one column
data = df_groups.apply(lambda row: [row['gene']] + row['all_mutations'], axis=1)
# convert dataframe back to list
result = data.to_list()

print(result)
```